# How to link ACF relationship field to the new Query block in Full Site Editing

Tags: categories, block-editor, advanced-custom-fields, archives, full-site-editing

I am using the new Query block on WordPress Full Site Editing and I am trying to figure out how to connect that to the ACF relationship field.

So I have an ACF field on my category that allows the user to pick a couple of posts and I need to pass these selected posts into the category template using the query block so they can edit the style of the posts.